# Boolean help: Testing the parameters for a password JAVA

Tags: java, boolean

#### Task:

This program should check if an entered password is at least 8 characters long, one upper and lowercase letter, a number, and a special character.

#### Code:

```
String password;
boolean hasLength;
boolean hasUppercase;
boolean hasLowercase;
boolean hasDigit;
boolean hasSpecial;

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
/******************************************************************************
*                             Inputs Section                                  *
******************************************************************************/
System.out.println("A password must be at least 8 character long");
System.out.println("And must contain:");
System.out.println("-At least 1 number");
System.out.println("-At least 1 uppercase letter");
System.out.println("-At least 1 special character (!@#$%^&*()_+)\n");
System.out.print("Please enter your new password: ");
password = scan.nextLine();

/******************************************************************************
*                           Processing Section                              *
******************************************************************************/
System.out.print("\n");
System.out.println("Entered Password:\t " + password);

hasLength = password.length() < 8; // parameters for length
// for lower and uppercase characters
hasUppercase = !password.equals(password.toUpperCase());
hasLowercase = !password.equals(password.toLowerCase());
hasDigit =  !password.matches("[0-9]");//checks for digits
hasSpecial = !password.matches("[A-Za-z]*"); //for anything not a letter in the ABC's


// the following checks if any of the instances are false, of so prints the statement
if(hasLength)
{
    System.out.println("Verdict: Invalid, Must have at least 8 characters");
}

if(!hasUppercase)
{
    System.out.println("Verdict: Invalid, Must have an uppercase Character");
}
if(!hasLowercase)
{
    System.out.println("Verdict: Invalid, Must have a lowercase Character");
}
if(!hasDigit)
{
    System.out.println("Verdict: Invalid, Must have a number");
}
if(!hasSpecial)
{
    System.out.println("Verdict: Invalid, Must have a special character");
}
```

If I input the password 'water' and I get:

```
Entered Password:    water
Verdict: Invalid, Must have at least 8 characters
Verdict: Invalid, Must have a lowercase Character
Verdict: Invalid, Must have a special character
```

Comment: `!password.equals(password.toLowerCase());` isn't testing for a "single" lower case character, but if the WHOLE password is lowercase, the same goes for your upper case check

Comment: I was going to say the same thing as that guy above me!

Comment: Oh wow, duh. What would be a good way of going about checking for a lowercase char. Going through and checking if each letter is upper or lowercase in something like an If loop?

Comment: You could use `hasUppercase = password.matches("(?s).*[A-Z]*");` and `hasLowercase = password.matches("(?s).*[a-z]*");` instead

Comment: Or `import static org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.*;  /* ... */  boolean ok = !isAllUpperCase(password) && !isAllLowerCase(password);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the upper and lowercase checks should be done vice-versa:

```
hasUppercase = !password.equals(password.toLowerCase());
hasLowercase = !password.equals(password.toUpperCase());
```

Because the lowercase version of the password equals the password, only if it does not contains uppercase letters.

The other two check can be done like this:

```
hasDigit = password.matches(".*[0-9].*");
hasSpecial = !password.matches("[A-Za-z0-9]*");
```